# Customize Explorer in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see this view in my visual studio code explorer

[image]

I want to remove outline, maven projects and open editors from my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the explorer by right-clicking `EXPLORER` and then un-checking "Outline" and "Open Editors".

See my screenshot below for reference:

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Code explorer settings]